# Reference request for t-distribution GARCH maximum-likelihood estimation

Tags: references, autoregressive, garch, t-distribution, quasi-maximum-likelihood

This [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=asqX90ieZ5w)'s second half formulates the GARCH autoregressive model combined with the heavy-tailed t-distribution (t-GARCH) and implies its log-likelihood function based on the first half's derivation for the Normal distribution. Although not written out in full for the t-GARCH, could someone provide the source article where the log-likelihood function is fully derived for the t-GARCH model?

(especially the more general case where the assumption of standard-t ($\mu=0,\sigma=1$) is relieved). Please don't just say "any GARCH textbook", I have looked, and they seldom count as the originator. just want to narrow the search faster

Comment: The assumption does not have to be relaxed, because in a GARCH model, the standardized residuals must have zero mean and unit variance by definition. Also, why the `quasi-maximum-likelihood` tag (and no `maximum-likelihood` tag) if you are specifically interested in maximum likelihood estimation for a given distribution (Student-$t$) rather than with a normal distribution (that would be quasi)? Also, when you say *autoregressive*, do you mean an AR-GARCH model, i.e. one where the conditional mean is modelled using an autoregression?

Comment: GARCH stands for generalized autoregressive conditional heteroskedasticity, so I wasn't implying the further case of AR-GARCH, no, just drawing out the terminology that GARCH is a type of autoregressive model that's all

Comment: OK, thanks. I was confused because *the GARCH autoregressive model* spells out as *the generalized autoregressive conditional heteroskedasticity autoregressive model* and as such contains the term *autoregressive* twice.

Comment: It's a good reminder that GARCH itself assumes $\mu=0,\sigma=1$ regardless of parametric distribution it is combined with. still waiting for that source though, even for the Gaussian-GARCH derivation

Comment: See ["Derivation of GARCH Student-$t$ log-likelihood"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/202553).

Comment: can we think of the log-likelihood function of t-GARCH in the same way that we think of the pdf equation of the t-distribution? if not, what then would be the pdf equation of t-GARCH

Comment: What do you mean more precisely by *think <...> in the same way*?

Comment: well the pdf equation of any parametric distribution forms a density curve. I'm not sure if a model's log-likelihood function forms a density curve, but even if we just look at the t-distribution alone, it has both a pdf equation and a log-likelihood function right? so what I'm interested in is whether GARCH models have a pdf equation

Comment: I guess you can think this way. What GARCH does is flatten or compress the pdf at different points in time, while ARMA shifts it right or left. So in an ARMA-GARCH model, the pdf is both shifting location and scale from one time period to another, but the overall shape remains the same.

Comment: I wonder if theres a way to see an illustration of what you mean, i.e. diagram of a pdf before and after being garched

Comment: It would be a sequence of 2D plots, one per time period, where the location shift is due to ARMA and the scale shift is due to GARCH. It is not difficult to obtain given the estimated model parameters, the assumed shape of the distribution (say, Student or Normal) and a function that outputs density from parameters such as `dnorm` or `dt` in R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For **GARCH-Student-$t$** model, the likelihood is available in MathWorks page ["Maximum Likelihood Estimation for Conditional Variance Models"](https://www.mathworks.com/help/econ/maximum-likelihood-estimation-for-conditional-variance-models.html) which references several sources. The relevant one is probably [Bollerslev (1987)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/1925546.pdf?refreqid=excelsior%3A76f4e1e6b969f67b57fd887ef9cdb954).
For **ARCH(m)-Student-$t$** model, the likelihood is available in [Hamilton (1994)](https://press.princeton.edu/books/hardcover/9780691042893/time-series-analysis) Chapter 21 Time Series Models of Heteroskedasticity, p. 662.
For **GARCH(p,q)-Normal** model, the likelihood is available in [Francq & Zakoian (2010)](https://www.wiley.com/en-no/GARCH+Models:+Structure,+Statistical+Inference+and+Financial+Applications,+2nd+Edition-p-9781119313489) Chapter 7 Estimating GARCH Models by Quasi-Maximum Likelihood, pp. 142.
For **ARCH(p)-Normal** model,  the likelihood is available in [Tsay (2010)](https://www.wiley.com/en-us/Analysis+of+Financial+Time+Series%2C+3rd+Edition-p-9780470414354) Chapter 3 Conditional Heteroskedastic Models, pp. 120.

**References**

- Bollerslev, T. (1987). [A conditionally heteroskedastic time series model for speculative prices and rates of return](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/1925546.pdf?refreqid=excelsior%3A76f4e1e6b969f67b57fd887ef9cdb954). *The Review of Economics and Statistics, 69*(3), p. 542-547.
- Francq, C., & Zakoian, J. M. (2010). [*GARCH Models: Structure, Statistical Inference and Financial Applications*](https://www.wiley.com/en-no/GARCH+Models:+Structure,+Statistical+Inference+and+Financial+Applications,+2nd+Edition-p-9781119313489). John Wiley & Sons.
- Hamilton, J. D. (1994). [*Time Series Analysis*](https://press.princeton.edu/books/hardcover/9780691042893/time-series-analysis). Princeton University Press.
- Tsay, R. S. (2010). [*Analysis of Financial Time Series* (3rd edition)](https://www.wiley.com/en-us/Analysis+of+Financial+Time+Series%2C+3rd+Edition-p-9780470414354). John Wiley & Sons.

Comment: Since the OP said *still waiting for that source though, even for the Gaussian-GARCH derivation*, I am providing what I found for the Gaussian case. I may follow it up with the Student-$t$ case later on.